# How to cite a report in APA style

Tags: style, technical-writing, citations, apa

I have been trying to go through Mayfield Book on Technical Writing to find out how to do an in-text and parenthetical citation of a source that I found online. The source looks like a report with statistics, facts and bar-charts with figures in education -- but nowhere is it mentioned that this a report. The source at the end of it mentions the following:

```
How to cite this product:
Turbo. Turbo Quick Take: Bridging the gender gap. New York: Turbo, 2012.
```

Are the following citations correct?
**Parenthetical**

```
Key indicators such as segregation and suggest that the situation might be improving (Turbo, 2012).
```

**In-text**

```
As stated in the Turbo (2012) report, ...
```

If not, what would be the correct way to cite this source?

Answer (score 2):

In the Bibliography:

> Turbo. (2012). *Turbo quick take: Bridging the gender gap.* New York: Turbo. Available online at http://www.whereveryoufoundit.com/path/to/document.pdf

In text:

> (Turbo, 2012, p. 7)

Google for the Purdue Online Writing Lab, or pick up a copy of the APA Manual at your local public library.